# Comma separated words to next line in new file

Tags: awk

I have a input file like this (input.txt):

```
Main1 one,two,three,four 
Main2 five,six,seven,eight
```

I want the output like this in output file (output.txt):

```
Main1 one
Main1 two
Main1 three
Main1 four

Main2 five
Main2 six
Main2 seven
Main3 eight
```

Answer (score 9):

```
awk '{ split($2,a,","); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]; }' input.txt
```

Example:

```
~) $ echo -e "Main1 one,two,th\nMain2 five,six,seven,eight " | awk '{ split($2,a,","); for (i in a) print $1, a[i]; }'
Main1 one
Main1 two
Main1 th
Main2 five
Main2 six
Main2 seven
Main2 eight
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some choices:

1. Shell

   ```
   while read main rest; do 
       for i in ${rest//,/$'\n'}; do 
           echo $main $i
       done
    done < file
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for split(/,/,$F[1])' file
   ```
3. awk

   ```
   awk -F'[, ]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}' file
   ```